# Tangled keyrings puzzle

Tags: visual, formation-of-numbers

Can you assign a unique number to all the keyring chains below and sort them accordingly?

[image]

After you finished, can you think of arrangements that give some other numbers, different from the 15 cases above? The rings have to stay connected.

Comment: Looks like how they made the olympics symbol :P

Comment: Safe to say that color is optional? I don't (yet?) notice any duplicate topologies.

Comment: @humn, color is optional, yes

Comment: [boboquack's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48241/18129) shows how exquisitely efficient the few clues are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are:

> [image: Values]

Because:

> For each keyring, you take the number of intersecting keyrings, then multiply all those numbers together to get the final result.

New value:

> [image: New value]

Sorted (Quite grainy, so refer to above images):

> [image: Sorted values]